# How to Redirect "site.com/filename" to "site.com/filename.html"?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I tried putting this code

```
Redirect 301 /pagename http://www.example.com/pagename.html
```

in my `.htaccess` file; but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this code into the .htaccess file instead:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

I found this answer on another forum and it works :)